# How to convert a single word into vector for neural network input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I am new to ML and thinking about one simple hello world problem as a practice of using ANN. Here is the problem, say I have a training data set with English name and its corresponding gender:

```
ALEX,M
BONNIE,F
CARLO,F
DAVID,M
EDDY,M
...
```

I would like to build a model to predict the gender of name. Since the input to ANN must be a form of vector, I am thinking to convert a name into a vector with a number of features same as the longest name in the data set (i.e. 10) and then put A=1, B=2, ... , Z=26, and null=-1 to the vector.

For example:

```
ALEX will be [1, 12, 5, 24, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

The output layer will be {0, 1} which represent either male or female.

It sounds quite strange to me. Is it a good way to feed a single word into ANN like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one-hot encoding. This means you have a large input size, but it has proven to work. Using `A=1, B=2, Z=26` gives the network the impression that B is closer to A than Z is to A, and it requires a lot of hidden nodes to map the function.

With one-hot encoding:

- A: `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
- B: `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`
- Z: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]`
- none: `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]`

So it requires 26 inputs per letter.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. By using one-hot input encoding, I can boost the accuracy from 60% to 85%. That's a great idea!

Comment: I'll allow myself a quick note: If you intend to use one-hot encoding on the output, be careful with loss functions. With large sparsities you might just end up training the network to predict all 0's.